# Similar OpenCV Api for interp2 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, opencv

Is there any similar function that works same as

```
interp2(x, y, frame(:,:,z), xd, yd, '*linear', 0)
```

in OpenCV?

Answer (score 1):

The function `cv::remap()` does almost what you're asking for, see the documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#remap).

You need to precompute the (x,y) target coordinates of the points in the input array(s) called `map1` and `map2` in the doc (use only one if you pack (x,y) coordinate, two otherwise).
The OpenCV equivalent to `'*linear'` is `cv::INTER_BILINEAR`.