# Using cv.remap (mexopencv) instead of interp2 (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, mex, bilinear-interpolation

I am experimenting with the [mexopencv](https://kyamagu.github.io/mexopencv) project that allows using the
[OpenCV](http://opencv.org) library from MATLAB `.m` files in order to compare the performance
of the native MATLAB functions with the OpenCV functions

I would like to substitute a call to the MATLAB [`interp2`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) function:

> `Vq = interp2(X,Y,V,Xq,Yq)` returns interpolated values of a function of two variables at specific query points using linear interpolation. The results always pass through the original sampling of the function. X and Y contain the coordinates of the sample points. V contains the corresponding function values at each sample point. Xq and Yq contain the coordinates of the query points.

The substitute shall be a call to the [`cv.remap`](https://kyamagu.github.io/mexopencv/matlab/remap.html) function.

> Applies a generic geometrical transformation to an image
>
> ```
> dst = cv.remap(src, map1, map2)
> dst = cv.remap(src, map1)
> dst = cv.remap(..., 'OptionName',optionValue, ...)
> ```

The three SO questions [Similar OpenCV Api for interp2 in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804128/similar-opencv-api-for-interp2-in-matlab), 
[How to do grid interpolation interp2 in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235379/how-to-do-grid-interpolation-interp2-in-opencv)
and [cv::remap (in opencv) and interp2 (matlab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912234/cvremap-in-opencv-and-interp2-matlab)
state that the OpenCV function `remap` can be used instead of the native MATLAB
function `interp2`, but I have no idea how-to correctly interpret/transform the
arguments (I have no experience regarding MATLAB and computer vision).

How can I use the mexopencv function `cv.remap` to get the same effect as if one
would call `Vq = interp2(X,Y,V,Xq,Yq)`?

Comment: Hum, I think the docs are quite clear, what do you have problem with?

Comment: I understand that `V` (`interp2`) is `src` (`cv.remap`) and `Vq` is `dst`, but I do not understand how `X`, `Y`, `Xq` and `Yq` should be mapped to `map1` and `map2`.

Comment: I believe that `(x,y)` is`map1` and `(xq,yq)` is `map2`

Comment: Sadly it seems not that simple (or can you provide me with a working example?)... I do not understand the concept of OpenCV maps. I am afraid I have to dig deeper and get a better understanding, e.g. maybe additional conversions are required. I had the hope that the conversion from MATLAB to OpenCV would be easier...